# program to calculate sales and visually display the customers order

Tags: java

Hello here is the prompt for my project

Write a program to calculate sales and visually
display. An online Cowboy retailer sells five products whose retail prices are as follows:
Product 1: Cowboy Boots, $74.99
Product 2: Wranglers, $25.99
Product 3: Cowboy Hats, $24.95
Product 4: Chaps, $ 34.89
Product 5: Spurs, $12.50
Write an application that reads the quantity for each product until user has completed their order. Your program should use switch, if, for, while and do while statements to
read, calculate and display the total retail value of all pro
ducts sold for each user transaction. The user should be able to start a new transaction after the first transaction is completed. The user can make no more than 3 total orders

```
public class Merchandise 
{
  private int bootsQTY;
  private int wranglersQTY;
  private int hatsQTY;
  private int chapsQTY;
  private int spursQTY;
  private double total;
  private double price;
  private int productNOM;

public Merchandise()
{
    total=price=0.00;
    productNOM=bootsQTY=wranglersQTY=hatsQTY=chapsQTY=spursQTY=0;
}

public int getBootsQTY()
{
    return bootsQTY;
}

public int getWranglersQTY()
{
    return wranglersQTY;
}

public int getHatsQTY()
{
    return hatsQTY;
}

public int getChapsQTY()
{
    return chapsQTY;
}

public int getSpursQTY()
{
    return spursQTY;
}

public double getTotal()
{
    return total;
}

public void setBootsQTY(int b)
{
    bootsQTY = b;
}

public void setWranglersQTY(int w)
{
    wranglersQTY = w;
}

public void setHatsQTY(int h)
{
    hatsQTY = h;
}

public void setChapsQTY(int c)
{
    chapsQTY = c;
}

public void setSpursQTY(int s)
{
    spursQTY = s;
}

public void inputOrder()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        String order = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Product 1: Cowboy Boots $74.99 \nProduct 2: Wranglers $25.99  \nProduct 3: Cowboy Hats $24.95 \nProduct 4: Chaps $34.89 \nProduct 5: Spurs $12.50 \nEnter the number of the product you would like to order, enter a -1 when your order is complete: ");
        productNOM = Integer.parseInt(order);

        boolean done = false;
        switch(productNOM)
        {
            case 1: 
                price = 74.99;
                String bQTY = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the quantity of Cowboy Boots you would like to order: ");
                setBootsQTY(Integer.parseInt(bQTY));
                break;
            case 2:
                price = 25.99;
                String wQTY = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the quantity of Wranglers you would like to order: ");
                setWranglersQTY(Integer.parseInt(wQTY));
                break;
            case 3:
                price = 24.95;
                String hQTY = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the quantity of Cowboy Hats you would like to order: ");
                setHatsQTY(Integer.parseInt(hQTY));
                break;
            case 4:
                price = 34.89;
                String cQTY = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the quantity of the chaps you would like to order: ");
                setChapsQTY(Integer.parseInt(cQTY));
                break;
            case 5:
                price = 12.50;
                String sQTY = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the quantity of Spurs you would like to order: ");
                setSpursQTY(Integer.parseInt(sQTY));
                break;
            default:
                done = true;
                break;
        }
        total += price * bootsQTY + price * wranglersQTY + price * hatsQTY + price * chapsQTY + price * spursQTY;


        if(!done)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }           
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString("Cowboys Boots $74.99 x" +getBootsQTY(), 25, 100);
    g.drawString("Wranglers     $25.99 x" +getWranglersQTY(), 25, 125);
    g.drawString("Cowboy Hats   $24.95 x" +getHatsQTY(), 25, 150);
    g.drawString("Chaps         $34.89 x" +getChapsQTY(), 25, 175);
    g.drawString("Spurs         $12.50 x" +getSpursQTY(), 25, 200);
    g.drawString("Total:                " +getTotal(), 25, 225);
}
}

public class MerchandiseComponent extends JComponent
{
private Merchandise merch;

public MerchandiseComponent(Merchandise m)
{
    merch = m;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Merchandise m = new Merchandise();
    m.draw(g2);
}
}

public class MerchandiseTester 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Merchandise merch = new Merchandise();

    merch.inputOrder();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(500, 750);
    frame.setTitle("Cowboy Store");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    MerchandiseComponent store = new MerchandiseComponent(merch);

    frame.add(store);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

When I run the program all of my quantities and total is 0, I can not figure out how to get values stored in them, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Merchandise class, can you please add an instance variable for each of those items price as example below?

```
    private double bootsPrice;
```

and assign the item price in switch case as example below?

```
     case 1: 
        bootsPrice = 74.99;
        String bQTY = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the quantity of Cowboy Boots you would like to order: ");
        setBootsQTY(Integer.parseInt(bQTY));
        break;
```

and for those items qty setter method,can you please add a "+' as example below?

```
    public void setBootsQTY(int b)
    {
       bootsQTY += b;
    }
```

and can you please change and put the total calculation in the if condition as below?

```
    if(!done)
    {
        total = (bootsPrice * bootsQTY) + (wranglersPrice * wranglersQTY) + (hatsPrice * hatsQTY) + (chapsPrice * chapsQTY) + (spursPrice * spursQTY);
        continue;
    }
```

On the other hand, in MerchandiseComponent class paintComponent method, can you please change as below?

```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
     merch.draw(g2);
    }
```

It print the correct quantity and value after the change. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have two instances of your Merchandise class.

One works out the prices and one displays them, because they are different instances they have different values.

Simply changing the displayed object to the one that has worked out the result will fix the display issue, see below:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    merch.draw(g2);
}
```